# prevent auto login on startup windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, login, automatic-logon

I know how i can disable auto logon in windows 7 by using `netplwiz`, but is there a way ( possibly a keyboard combination pressed during startup ) that will prevent autologon only for this one boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold down the shift key while the machine starts.

You may need a hotfix for this to work, [support.microsoft.com/kb/977534](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977534)

Comment: That short URL took me to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977534.  Do you really believe that that URL is so long that it needs to be shortened?  It’s probably better to post the true URL in your answer, so people will be able to see that it is a trustworthy site, and not be faced with a mystery URL that might lead to a malware site, for all we know.

Comment: @Scott Hey, check my rep, I wouldn't post malware here :-), I use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/context-menu-url-shortene/ecehogjcciopmihcocdchiaciibinajf) for chrome, in addition to shortening the url, it's also a right click on the page to copy, so in some cases it's *alot* easier to copy the url that way.

Comment: I have got the Shift key to work, but the timing can be tricky, I only press the shift after the initial boot phase, just before the user would log on.

Comment: @GuyThomas the timing is tricky indeed, I usually only have to deal with this *after* the account has logged on, in which case I can hold the shift key while clicking the logoff button and indefinitely until I'm prompted with ctl+alt+del again.

Answer (score -2):

If you alternate right - left shift keys very quickly well Windows is booting it will bypass the auto log on and take you to a log on screen.

Comment: How does this improve on the two existing answers that both mention the use of the shift key?